# recv() with MSG_DONTWAIT flag set doesn't recieve data from TCP socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send, recv

I am in the process of writing a basic server and client chatting application in FreeBSD c. Basically multiple clients connect to the server on multiple ports (Ex. ports 4, 5, 6, 7), those ports are stored in an array which is constantly iterated through looking for data sent over by the corresponding clients. I am using recv(port#, buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_DONTWAIT), in order to support non blocking of the ports. This method works when I use the read() method with blocking, but it is not working when I use the recv method with the non blocking, more specifically it will receive data from the first port in the array but not the other ones. Logically I think my code works, Im just looking for any insight on possible problems with recv, or if anyone knows how to fix this.

```
void* chat_room(int chatid){
    printf("Entered Chatroom %d\n", chatid);
    int i = 0;
    int n;
    char buffer[150];
    while(1){

    int *array = create_chat_array(chatid);

           while(new_chatter != chatid){
            i = 0;
            while(array[i] != -1){

                n = recv(array[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_DONTWAIT);

                    if(n > 0){
                            printf("Recieved %s, from %d\n", buffer, array[i]);
                    }


                i++;
            }
    }

}

}
```

This is the code for the chatroom, Basically it iterates through the array and tries to read. It always reads from array[0] but not from any of the other ones. Any insight would be helpful

Comment: You need to check `errno` in the cases where `recv()` returns -1, and post it here.

Comment: Rather running a "busy loop", a better idea may be to use 'poll()' or 'select()'.  Additionally, you say clients connect on different ports, and those ports are put in an array and you 'read' from them... Don't You really mean clients connect with different 'sockets', and the socket descriptors are put into an array and you read from them..?

Comment: Yeah tony thats what I meant to say. Ill look into using select instead. Also the errno was 35 - EDEADLK /* Resource deadlock would occur */ If thats of any help

Comment: I doubt it. It isn't documented to yield that error. More likely it was `EWOULDBLOCK`, which just mean there was no data available. Did you test/get `errno` immediately after the failure, without calling any more functions? You should use `perror()` or `strerror()` here.

Comment: Actually, all the client requests initially come in on the same port.  The initial handshake tells the client which port to use for further communication with the server.